How to override a nested parameter in AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3 pipeline task
I'm attempting to deploy a VM via an ARM template using AZDO pipeline. The sample template and parameters file provided by Microsoft is quite long, with each configuration setting as its own individual parameter. I've condensed the parameters file by using JSON objects similar to the format below:
{
 "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
 "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
 "parameters": {
     "config": {
         "location": "eastus"
         "extensions": {
             "extension1": {
                 "apiKey": ""
             }
         }
     }
 }
}

We need to deploy these VM's with specific extensions installed, some of which require sensitive information for proper configuration. Normally, if the "apiKey" field was a normal parameter / on the same level as the "config" parameter in my above example, I would override the parameter in the pipeline task with the secret retrieved from our Key Vault like the following:
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
 inputs:
   overrideParameters: '-apiKey $(extension1APIKey)'

However, since the apiKey property is nested inside multiple properties, I'm wondering if the following is correct:
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
 inputs:
   overrideParameters: '-config.extensions.extension1.apiKey $(extension1APIKey)'

If it's not, what's the proper way to override nested properties/parameters?
Thank you.

According to the overrideParameters in the task AzureResourceGroupDeployment

To override object type parameters, use stringified JSON objects. For example, -options ["option1"] -map {"key1": "value1" }.

So, I can use object type parameters in the following format to override the apiKey:
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  displayName: 'ARM Template deployment: Resource Group scope'
  inputs:
    overrideParameters: '-config {"location":"eastus","extensions":{"extension1":{"apiKey":"$(extension1APIKey)"}}}'

The template parameters file:
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters":{
        "config": {
            "value": {
                "location": "eastus",
                "extensions": {
                    "extension1":{
                        "apiKey": ""
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

The template file:
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "config": {
            "type": "object"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            //other Configurations
            //...
            
            "config": "[parameters('config')"
            
        }
    ]
}


The reason why it's invalid is because the "config" parameter doesn't have "value". That is not the problem. The example that I provided was just using pseudo-code. The question still stands: "How do I override a nested parameter?"

Hi @yamh, thanks for your reminder. I have updated the answer with the object type parameters usage. Hope it can help with the issue.

Hi @yamh, can the object type parameters usage help you override the nested parameter? If you need more help, please let me know.
